# OCR Reader WS Upgrade from .Net Framework 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ocr

I have been tasked with converting an old .Net 2.0 application to 4.0 and am running into a build error related to a missing dependency.

The build error is as follows:

Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'Atalasoft.dotImage.Ocr.GlyphReader.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I was thinking that I needed to find a newer version of this DLL but I wanted to see if anyone knew an easier method for resolving this first.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

A .NET 4.0 or later assembly can reference and use an assembly built on the .NET 2.0 framework. The problem is that the compiler cannot find the assembly, not that the assembly is the wrong version. Try the following steps, this should clear up your problem:

1. Highlight the reference in the project and go the the properties tab (F4 shortcut). Check the path that is used to reference the assembly and verify that it is actually located there.
2. Check if the project requires a specific version of the assembly. Go to the same properties page like mentioned in step 1 and see if specific version is set to true, change it to false if this is not a requirement for you.
3. If you are using NuGet ensure that the latest assemblies have been downloaded if you are not persisting your references to the source repository. You check this by going to the nuget project references and in the top right corner there will be a message asking you if you want to restore all package references if they cannot be found.
4. If you are not using nuget for this and it still does not work then remove the reference and manually re-add it to the project.